# How can I change the game executable name to something other than UE4.exe?

Tags: unreal-4, windows, export

I have a game and when I export it it is called Bounced! but in windows task manager the process appears as UE4.exe but with the logo of my game, how can I change this to Bounced.exe?

Comment: could it be because the compiled game is running on UE4, I mean I've played games before that show up in task manager as the engine their running on before.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the executable is dictated by the name of your ***.uproject** project file when you first create your project and package it, so if you already have an existing project called something like "UE4", you won't be able to change the name of the executable - it will always have the same name as the name of the project.

To change it on an existing project, it seems like you'll have to make a new project with a new *.uproject file, copy the old project over to the new project directory, delete the old .*uproject file, and then run it again and repackage it. Alternatively, you can rename that *.uproject file and then make any code changes to reference the new project name as needed, depending on if your project is blueprint-based or not. [(**Source**)](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/520140/specify-the-name-of-packaged-exe.html?sort=oldest)

Comment: The source you link doesn't mention creating a new project and copying it over. Instead it says to rename the uproject file for a blueprint project, or make additional code changes for a code project. Is there a reason you'd recommend the new project route over this approach?

Comment: The executable has the corret name but in Task Manager doesn appear correct

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of Unreal might be a little different, but this worked for me on 5.3:

1. Rename the `.uproject` file to the new name. This does not change the executable name, but does change the name of the directory that the game data is stored in. You should be able to just directly rename it without editing anything inside of it.
2. Open your `Source` folder and rename the two `.Target.cs` files. Edit them and change the class name to match the new file names (without the `.Target` part). The name of the non-editor "target" will be what is used for the executable name. You do not need to change the names of the any of the modules in `Source`; just change the `.target` files.
3. Delete your `Binaries/Win64`, `Intermediate`, and `Saved` folders, regenerate the project files and rebuild. You might be able to omit deleting some of them, but I find that this is the safest option.  NOTE: deleting "Saved" will reset your editor preferences and source control settings.

When you do a new build, it should now use the new name.

Comment: OP is asking about changing the process name that appears in the windows task manager. It looks like your solution is addressing the executable name (i.e. how it appears in the file manager). Can you confirm that your solution also changes the task manager name?

Comment: Yes, the task manager (at least in Windows 11) uses the executable name by default.